Using Bode plots for locking a laser to a cavity
I am new to this topic, but I am trying to understand how to use Bode plots to optimize my PID loop parameters for PDH locking a laser to an ultrastable cavity. For simplicity (and based on what I have read so far), let's say that the open loop gain (including the plant and controller) is K. Then, the transfer function for the closed loop is $$\frac{K}{1+K}$$
Now, I have several questions:

This transfer function gives be the behavior of the output given the input for a given frequency. However, in my case, the input (which is the value I want my laser frequency to have) is a fixed value and thus not frequency dependent. So it seems like all I need from the transfer function is the value at zero frequency. What do I need the rest for in this case?
If I am to add noise, that noise is multiplied by $$\frac{1}{1+K}$$ in the equation relating the input with the output.
In this case, the frequency comes into play, as the noise has a spectrum. Maximizing K as much as possible is useful, as it minimizes the noise and increases the bandwidth i.e., the larger the noise frequencies I can cancel. However, it's not clear to me how knowing the transfer function (first equation), e.g. by measuring it in practice, allows me to compute the second equation. K can be a very complicated function of frequency, so going from one to the other is not trivial (if possible at all). Also, if I can measure the second formula directly, why do I need the transfer function in the first place? Basically for this and previous question, I am trying to understand what can I use the Bode for in practice.
The servo box I am using is this one. In Fig. 4 of that page they show the Gain of the feedback loop (at least this is what they claim). How is this useful, given that in practice the other elements in the system contribute to the closed loop gain? Wouldn't the open loop gain be more useful, such that I can combine it with the open gain of the other elements to get the overall theoretical closed loop gain? Also, why don't they show the phase vs frequency? Isn't that very important to asses the stability, too?
How can I adjust the knobs available in relation to figure 4 in order to maximize my locking? What steps would I need to take in practice/experimentally to find the best locking parameters?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The loop gain is a frequency-dependent expression and is usually noted $T(s)$. $T$ is the product of a plant control-to-output transfer function $H$ - an expression describing the magnitude/phase frequency response of the process you want to control - by the compensator $G$, which is an active or passive filter shaping the loop gain to meet specific parameters such as crossover frequency and phase/gain margins. A PID is one type of compensator: $T(s)=H(s)G(s)$. The starting point is thus the ac response $H(s)$ of the process you want to control from which you deduce $G(s)$.

Sorry in my notation above K would be T (I didn't know there is a convention for that). So what is the plot in Fig 4 above? Is it G(s)? But G(s), as far as I understand is the open loop gain the of the controller, while in their explanation they call it the gain of the feedback loop, which would be T(s). However, one can't know T(s) without knowing the rest of the setup, so I am confused.

It is difficult to say as I am not expert in laser control but it seems that fig. 4 relates to the possible frequency response of $G(s)$, the compensator which features two poles as they describe it. Tweaking these parameters manually will let you shape the loop gain but it seems like a trial-and-error type of approach.
